# what is the type of `std::greater` or `std::less_equal`

Tags: c++, stl

```
template <class T> struct greater : binary_function <T,T,bool> {
  bool operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const
    {return x>y;}
};

template <class T> struct logical_and : binary_function <T,T,bool> {
  bool operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const
    {return x&&y;}
};

// (i > 5 && i <=10)
countBoost = std::count_if(vecInts.begin(), vecInts.end(),
                           boost::bind(std::logical_and<bool>(), 
                                                        ^^^^ // ???? Why ????
                                    boost::bind(std::greater<int>(),    _1, 5),
                                    boost::bind(std::less_equal<int>(), _1, 10))
                          );
```

Based on my understanding, the pass-in type `T` for `std::logical_and<T>` is the type of the pass-in parameters of function `operator()`. Given the above code, it seems that the type of `std::greater` is `bool` that is determined by the returned value of  `operator()`.

Is that correct?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boost binder does a bit more magic than what you might be expecting. When one of the bound arguments is a bind expression itself, it will *execute* that expression during the call and use the result. In this case, the internal bound expressions are calls to `std::less<int>` and `std::greater<int>`, both of which yield a `bool`, which is then passed to the `std::logical_and<bool>`.

Answer (score 2):

The return type of the `operator()` function is bool.  The type of
`std::greater` is `std::greater`.  It's a functional object.  Thus:

```
std::greater<int> g;
std::cout << typeof( g ).name() << std::endl;
```

will return whatever your compiler uses to display the instantiation
type of a class template: `"struct std::greater<int>"` for VC++, for
example.